# How javascript Promise works

Tags: javascript, promise

I have this script that get random videos in the web.

The function `getRandomVideo()` returns a Promise with a list of urls.

What I want to do is print the data by calling `main().then(data => console.log(data))`. The problem is that data is being printed before the function is done running. So when I start the program I get `undefined` and then after the function is done I get the actual data.
I thought that what is inside `.then()` would run just after the promise is returned.
Does anyone know what is happening?

```js
const main = async () => {
  let allData = [];

  getRandomVideo().then((videoLinks) => {
    allData = videoLinks;

    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      resolve(allData);
    });
  });
};

main().then((data) => console.log(data));
```

Comment: so many anti patterns in so few lines. 1. you're using `async`, never `await`. You're using `.then` in an `async` function. you needlessly (in this code) create a `new Promise` inside a `.then`

Comment: your `main` function has no `return`, so, it returns a Promise that resolves to `undefined` - immediately, without caring what `getRandomVideo` does

Comment: your main function can simply be declared `const main = () => { return gettRandomVideo(); }` - or `const main = () => gettRandomVideo();` ... or ... wait for it ... `const main = gettRandomVideo;` and it will work as intended - note the total lack of `async`

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, your code is full of anti-patterns in an attempt to avoid the basics of asynchronous programming with promises.  All you need is this:

```
const main = function() => {
    return getRandomVideo();
}

main().then(data => console.log(data)).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Or, of course, you don't even need `main()` at all.  You can just do:

```
getRandomVideo().then(data => console.log(data)).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Some anti-patterns in your original code:

1. Not returning anything from your `main()` function.
2. Assigning an asynchronous value to a higher scoped variable and hoping that it somehow fixes asynchronous programming issues.  It is nearly always a warning that you're doing something wrong when you assign an asynchronously retrieved value to a higher scoped variable because the code in the higher scope generally has no idea when that value will actually be available.  Only within the `.then()` handler so you know when the value is present.
3. Manually creating a promise for no particular reason.
4. Marking a function `async` for no reason.
5. No error handling (e.g. `.catch()` handler) when calling a function that returns a promise.

If you want to manipulate the results of getRandomVideo before you send it back to the caller, then you could have a reason to use `async/await`

```
const main = async () => {
    let videos = await getRandomVideo();
    // define some filter function for the videos array and 
    // return the filtered result as the resolved value
    return videos.filter(...);
}

main().then(data => console.log(data)).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: or `const main = gettRandomVideo;`

Answer (score -2):

I think we can understand main function step by step:

1. let `allData = [];` //Defined allData variable
2. call getRandomVideo function
3. The thread wait getRandomVideo completed and return videoLinks array when you call .then function
4. allData = videoLinks; //Asign videoLinks array to allData variable
5. return new Promise((resolve) => { resolve(allData) }) //Return a Promise, that will tell the thread that you will do that later, on the other hand, after few second it's will comback and return all data by call resolve function
6. End of main function
   ==>> So as you can see, main function don't return a Promise imediately, you can't use .then to wait until it completed
   Solution: Let wrap main function detail by a Promise like that

   const main= () => {
   return new Promise((resolve) => {
   getRandomVideo().then((videoLinks) => {
   resolve(videoLinks);
   });
   });
   }

And clean your code by drop allData variable.